# c++: how to print new line without carriage return

Tags: c++, printing, carriage-return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make cout behave as in binary mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654067/how-to-make-cout-behave-as-in-binary-mode)

I am using C++ to print binary data to the stdout and then I redirect it to a file.
(I do not want to write directly to a file).
However, when I try to print the value `'0A'` I am getting `'0D 0A'`. (this is what I see when I copy the output to HexEdit).
From what I can figure out, `'0A'` is the ascii for 'new line' so cout automatically adds the `'0D'` which is *'carriage return'*.
What I want is to print `0A` alone. how can I do this?

my code:

```
unsigned char *buf = new unsigned char[width+1];
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) 
{
    buf[x] = (unsigned char) src[x];
}
buf[width] = '\0'
cout<<buf;
```

I've seen this: [Print new line to a text file without carriage return (CR) in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7579983/print-new-line-to-a-text-file-without-carriage-return-cr-in-windows) but it does not seem to help me.

Comment: Why link you mentioned does not help you?

Comment: @Lol4t0: the link points to a C question, not a C++ one.

Comment: This does not really matter, the thing is that TS should reopen `stdout` in binary mode.

Comment: Thanks to all. what I ended up doing was using _setmode to set the mode of stdout to binary. `fd_stdout = fdopen (1,"wb"); _setmode( _fileno( stdout ), _O_BINARY );` and then I used fwrite to write my binary data to stdout `fwrite(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buf), width, 1, fd_stdout);`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure you really can use cout and the `<<` operator without a massive hack. This is because when using `<<` cout treats all data as text data and will perform appropriate transformations as necessary -- including adding a CR character when printing a newline on a Windows platform.

You will need to use the `write` method of cout, instead of using the insertion operator `<<`. The `write` method will not format your data, but is more awkward to use.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/write/

Comment: even when using `write()` the `\n` gets replaced with an end of line sequence. The conversion is either done on the stream buffer level or on systems even by the system call.

Comment: I did the following:  cout.setf(std::ios_base::binary);
 cout.write((const char*)buf, width); and I still get the carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

You can't control the end of line sequence with any of the standard output streams or files. The only way to deal with this is to `freopen()` the standard output `stdout` with an open mode of `wb` or wb+` to control the underlying formatting, e.g.:

```
FILE* out = freopen("stdout.txt", "wb", stdout);
std::cout << "hello, world\n";
```

If you are only using C++ streams you can also replace `std::cout`'s stream buffer with the stream buffer of an appropriately opened `std::ofstream`, e.g.:

```
std::ofstream   file("stdout.txt", std::ios_base::out);
std::streambuf* coutbuf = std::cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
std::cout << "hello, world\n";
...
std::cout.rdbuf(coutbuf);
```

You need to restore the original stream buffer to avoid problems with uses of `std::cout` during destruction: at the very least the stream gets flushed at some point after `main()` is exited. If you can accept a memory leak, you can use a dynamically allocated `std::filebuf` directly.

None of the solutions above actually writes the output to the standard output, they all write to a file. I don't know how to reopen the standard output on a Windows system (on a UNIX system you'd either create a stream buffer using file descriptor `1` but on UNIX there is no need anyway because the `\n` doesn't get replaced in the first place). In particular, reopening the stream to fit in with output redirection is probably not possible.